# Map Grid is flickr while navigating back

Tags: xamarin

I used Esri.ArcGISRuntime.Xamarin.Forms packages for display map in xamarin.on navigation to previous page Map Grid is Flicker and show black screen for few second and then navigate to previous page.Is there any way to remove black screen on map.
For display Map I write This Code
"esriUI:MapView x:Name="uxMapView" BackgroundColor="White"

On back button click I write this code
 _ = Navigation.PopAsync();

Comment: Hi Sangita, you will need to share more of your code for us to understand whats going on. What class is displaying the map? What is the class that is launching that page? Can you change the background of all the screens to red, are you still seeing the black screen?

Comment: Please share us a Minimal, Reproducible Example?

Comment: Hi, I have uploaded project on git hub  link:                                                                                                    https://github.com/sangitamalviya/DisplayAcrgisMap                                                                       in This Demo On   Back Navigation button click Map Will be Flicker.Is there any way to remove flicker on map.